# How can I highlight the search text in Apache Solr?

Tags: apache, search, solr, highlight, solrj

I am using Apache Solr for indexing and searching with SolrJ in java/GWT.

When I search for specific word or text then in the result I want to highlight that search text i.e. the search text is displayed in highlighted manner in the result...
help me how can I implement this in my application....if anyone knows any solution...

Thanking in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Solr Highlight](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters/) for this. By default hightlight component is enabled in `solrconfig.xml`. You can configure [fragmenters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#The_Highlighter_plugin_configuration_section) inside the highlightComponent section in `solrconfig.xml` file.

You can also set highlighting parameters inside requestHandler such as :

```
   <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
   <str name="hl">on</str>
   <str name="hl.fl">text features name</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
```

Then you can query solr as follows, which will list the highlighted keywords inside  tags.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=keyword&hl=true
```

Comment: Answers that are little more than a link are considered "low-quality" on StackExchange. You can expand on your answer to make it more self-contained and then point to a more exhaustive resource.

Comment: Thank you for your warning, but I wanted to show at least a way to begin.

Comment: @pravin: thanks for your reply...
 Can you please give me the example...How can I do that programatically...I am new to Solr so do not have good idea...

Comment: Updated answer.hope it will help you.